# Is it a good idea to redirect expected page name misspellings/typos for critical web pages?

Tags: urls, errors, seo, error-prevention, redirect

For example, would redirecting `www.example.com/loogin` to `www.example.com/login` be fine?

Would it be better to automatically redirect users to the correct page or display a page stating that the user is going to be redirected to the correct page in a couple of seconds? Would this have any disadvantages on the SEO?

Also, the user profile URLs are going to be in the following format `www.example.com/user/johndoe` which would not have the users create anything on the web root.

I’m only asking this because I have noticed major social media websites such as Facebook, Twitter and Pinterest are allowing this. Facebook `www.facebook.com/loogin` has an active user, while both Twitter `www.twitter.com/loogin` and Pinterest `pinterest.com/loogin` appear to have dead accounts.

Interestingly, Vine does not have `vine.co/loogin` registered to a user and displays a 404 on visit, yet it does not allow users to register it.

I have used [SEOBook Keyword Type Generator Tool](http://tools.seobook.com/spelling/keywords-typos.cgi) to generate all the possible `login` typos and here are the results. If the above it a good idea, would it be fine to make all typos redirect?

```
ogin, lgin, loin, logn, logi, llogin, loogin, loggin, logiin, loginn, olgin, lgoin, loign, logni, kogin, oogin, pogin, ligin, l9gin, l0gin, lpgin, llgin, lkgin, lofin, lotin, loyin, lohin, lobin, lovin, logun, log8n, log9n, logon, logln, logkn, logjn, logib, logih, logij, logim, klogin, lkogin, ologin, loogin, plogin, lpogin, liogin, loigin, l9ogin, lo9gin, l0ogin, lo0gin, lpogin, lopgin, llogin, lolgin, lkogin, lokgin, lofgin, logfin, lotgin, logtin, loygin, logyin, lohgin, loghin, lobgin, logbin, lovgin, logvin, loguin, logiun, log8in, logi8n, log9in, logi9n, logoin, logion, loglin, logiln, logkin, logikn, logjin, logijn, logibn, loginb, logihn, loginh, logijn, loginj, logimn, loginm
```

Comment: Rather than trying to come up with thousands of typo variations, most of which probably never actually get accidentally typed would it not just be better to serve a page that contains the options 'did you mean login' AND 'or continue to loogin' rather than run the risk of putting out of operations said thousands of URL's which may actually be wanted by legitimate users?

Comment: @zigojacko But it wouldn't make sense to redirect `www.example.com/signuup` to the login page. I'm talking about redirecting related typos to their relevant pages.

Comment: Yes I know. Same applies. Depending on the typo, serve a message asking if they actually mean [insert link to most likely meant page] or if they did indeed mean what they typed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it’s a good idea.

Especially if you notice that there are some misspelled links out there, e.g. if someone links to your login page with `/login.` instead of `/login` (because the URL auto-detection of their CMS thought that the dot for ending a sentence belongs to the URL).

*Preventively* adding such redirects is probably not of a high priority, however, it can’t hurt (unless maybe the performance, depending on your implementation). I’d only add the most common misspellings, and watch your error logs for more to add.

I think the best choice would be a 301 Redirect. Adding a notice to the page would instruct your users that the URL they followed is "wrong", but as long as you keep the redirects working, there is no strong need to bother them with this. So "silently" redirect, with 301 so that search engines and other bots know that the initial URL should not be used, and everyone is happy.

The problem with Facebook’s `/login` vs. `/loogin` is exactly [why URL path prefixes should be used](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86990/17633), either for the user names (starting with something like `/user/`) or for the internal pages (starting with a character that user names can’t start with).

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: yes.

Extended answer: Yes and no.

The main problem here, which I think has been made clear, is that for you to identify all of the possible mistakes (which is hard to plan for) and redirect them all is more effort than it's worth (unless you're Google, but even then...).

An alternative solution would be to create a 404 page that offers suggestions. This could be different for different types of sites. An e-commerce site might suggest the product page, as well as related products to the mistyped word. Another site may suggest a single page. In any case, a user should be provided with a link back to the Home page and/or possibly the opportunity to search from where they are. Like "Hey, we didn't find what you were looking for, try searching".

But ultimately, I think it varies case-by-case. Some companies can afford to buy related domains to help the redirect. Others can't. Other factors, like the ease of a copmany's name (and along with it, how likely a user is to make a typo) should be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is that such redirections are only really helpful when you expect the user to need to type the URL of that page. So if you do it at all, it's probably going to be more useful for links that you expect people will see in things like print ad campaigns, where they can't just directly click on the link in the first place.

Looking at the analytics for your site can also help determine which pages people have directly accessed, and thus which URLs they might have typed themselves. But even then, only a small percentage of the direct access traffic you see will be people who actually *have* typed the address... the majority will still likely be people using bookmarks, or URL shorteners, or links from https websites (if your website is not https), or any of the other things that can cause referrer information not to be passed. You can [read more about interpreting direct traffic here](https://megalytic.com/blog/understanding-direct-traffic-in-google-analytics).